# Build a json array from multiple properties of a custom type in Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, loops, codable

After being pointed towards using Codable to format json in Swift, I am trying to add multiple results to a json array. I am unfortunately struggling to work out how to build this json array for a set of results that contains multiple properties.

Here is an example of my required json array for two 'sets' of results (N.B. the number of sets can vary in the data recorded):

```
[{"record":"10","redcap_repeat_instrument":"range_of_motion_result","redcap_repeat_instance":"1","field_name":"orientation_forward","value":"2"},
{"record":"10","redcap_repeat_instrument":"range_of_motion_result","redcap_repeat_instance":"1","field_name":"start_forward","value":"3.45"},
{"record":"10","redcap_repeat_instrument":"range_of_motion_result","redcap_repeat_instance":"1","field_name":"finish_forward","value":"5.29"},
{"record":"10","redcap_repeat_instrument":"range_of_motion_result","redcap_repeat_instance":"1","field_name":"minimum_forward","value":"7.81"},
{"record":"10","redcap_repeat_instrument":"range_of_motion_result","redcap_repeat_instance":"1","field_name":"maximum_forward","value":"9.20"},
{"record":"10","redcap_repeat_instrument":"range_of_motion_result","redcap_repeat_instance":"1","field_name":"range_forward","value":"2.39"},
{"record":"10","redcap_repeat_instrument":"range_of_motion_result","redcap_repeat_instance":"2","field_name":"orientation_forward","value":"1"},
{"record":"10","redcap_repeat_instrument":"range_of_motion_result","redcap_repeat_instance":"2","field_name":"start_forward","value":"1.89"},
{"record":"10","redcap_repeat_instrument":"range_of_motion_result","redcap_repeat_instance":"2","field_name":"finish_forward","value":"4.20"},
{"record":"10","redcap_repeat_instrument":"range_of_motion_result","redcap_repeat_instance":"2","field_name":"minimum_forward","value":"8.26"},
{"record":"10","redcap_repeat_instrument":"range_of_motion_result","redcap_repeat_instance":"2","field_name":"maximum_forward","value":"46.82"},
{"record":"10","redcap_repeat_instrument":"range_of_motion_result","redcap_repeat_instance":"2","field_name":"range_forward","value":"2.98"}]
```

And below is my Swift code. The results arrive as an argument within an array of custom type `ORKRangeOfMotionResult` (from `ResearchKit` with each set of results giving me a value for `orientation`, `start`, `finish`, `minumum`, `maximum` and `range` properties). Each set of `ORKRangeOfMotionResult` is also accompanied by an identifier (`variableIdentifier`), pulled in as another result that I can use to ensure I know which set is which.

I am currently using a loop to extract individual values for each `ORKRangeOfMotionResult` property. After this, it is relatively easy to add one result to the json array `[items]` using the `variableIdentifier` in `if` statements (as can be seen below for `start`) but I don't know how to add all properties from a set of results to the array. I'm guessing a loop, but haven't figured out how as yet.

```
func buildJsonArrayOfResults(_ rangeOfMotionResults: [ORKRangeOfMotionResult], withIdentifier variableIdentifiers: [String]) {
    let record = getIDNumber().stringValue
    let repeat_instance = getRepeatInstance().stringValue
    let repeat_instrument = "range_of_motion_result"
    let event = getEventName()
    var fieldName: String?
    var identifier: String?
    var stringData: String?
    var value: String?
    var items: [Item] = []
        
    struct Item: Codable {
        let record: String
        let fieldName: String
        let repeatInstance: String
        let repeatInstrument: String
        let value: String
        let event: String

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case record
            case fieldName = "field_name"
            case repeatInstance = "redcap_repeat_instance"
            case repeatInstrument = "redcap_repeat_instrument"
            case value
            case event = "redcap_event_name"
        }
    }
        
    var setNumber: Int = 0
    while setNumber < rangeOfMotionResults.count {
        setNumber += 1
            
        // obtain results for each set of movements as a string
        let orientation = String(rangeOfMotionResults[setNumber - 1].orientation)
        let start = String(rangeOfMotionResults[setNumber - 1].start)
        let finish = String(rangeOfMotionResults[setNumber - 1].finish)
        let minimum = String(rangeOfMotionResults[setNumber - 1].minimum)
        let maximum = String(rangeOfMotionResults[setNumber - 1].maximum)
        let range = String(rangeOfMotionResults[setNumber - 1].range)
            
        // assign one value and its redcap field name
        identifier = variableIdentifiers[setNumber - 1]
        if identifier!.contains("forward") {
            fieldName = "start_forward"
            value = start
        } else if identifier!.contains("backward") {
            fieldName = "start_backward"
            value = start
        } else if identifier!.contains("left.bending") {
            fieldName = "start_left_bending"
            value = start
        } else if identifier!.contains("right.bending") {
            fieldName = "start_right_bending"
            value = start
        } else if identifier!.contains("left.rotation") {
            fieldName = "start_left_rotation"
            value = start
        } else if identifier!.contains("right.rotation") {
            fieldName = "start_left_rotation"
            value = start
        }
            
        let item = Item(record: record, fieldName: fieldName!, repeatInstance: String(repeat_instance), repeatInstrument: repeat_instrument, value: value!, event: event)
            
        items.append(item)
    }

    do {
        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(items)
        stringData = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print(stringData!)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    // now do something with stringData

}
```

All hep graciously received. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about using an Enum String for `variableIdentifiers` instead? And add a extra method/computed var which would give a `fieldName`? What about making also `fieldName` an Enum String? You use a `while` loop, and `-1` each time, but you could remove the `-1` and increment at the end of the loop, or even use a for loop. Also, what's `ORKRangeOfMotionResult`? You are doing `String(aORKRangeOfMotionResultProperty)` each time. Aren't they already strings?

Comment: Thanks @Larme. `ORKRangeOfMotionResult` is from `ResearchKit` and are returned as `NSNumber`. I'm just trying to think through your suggestions...

Comment: @Larme My brain can't cope with too large a departure from C-style `for loops`, but yes I could increment at the end and remove the `-1` each time. I've added a reference to `ResearchKit` in the question now. The `variableIdentifiers` will be slightly different for each set and the order of these will be randomised per set of results, but will always contain certain characters (hence why I used `.contains`). Still can't work out the solution from your suggestions - sorry (my fault I'm sure)!

Comment: Where does `event` come from?

Comment: `// obtain results for each set of movements as a string` You almost don't use the values, and some properties for the init of `Item` are coming from where?

Comment: sorry - copy/paste errors trying to clean the code. they will be pulled in from elsewhere as required parameters by redcap database. I will add their init to answer

Comment: @Larme Precisely the problem I have is that I din't know how best to use the values that I get from the `ORKRangeOfMotionResult`. I want to iterate through these and build the json array accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answer from @vadian, I was able to completely solve this by adding a new `struct` containing a `key-value pair` with an identifier (and an `array` of these 'trios') and then adding a second `for-in loop`. I'm sure my code can be optimised some more (this would be interesting to see) but I'm very pleased (and grateful) that this is now building the json array in the way I wanted. Here is my final solution:

```
func buildJsonArrayOfResults(_ rangeOfMotionResults: [ORKRangeOfMotionResult], withIdentifier variableIdentifiers: [String]) {
    
    let record = getIDNumber().stringValue
    let repeatInstance = getRepeatInstance().stringValue
    let repeatInstrument = "range_of_motion_result"
    let event = getEventName()
    var fieldName: String?
    var identifier: String?
    var stringData: String?
    var value: String?
    var items: [Item] = []
        
    struct Item: Codable {
        let record: String
        let fieldName: String
        let repeatInstance: String
        let repeatInstrument: String
        let value: String
        let event: String

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case record
            case fieldName = "field_name"
            case repeatInstance = "redcap_repeat_instance"
            case repeatInstrument = "redcap_repeat_instrument"
            case value
            case event = "redcap_event_name"
        }
    }
        
    struct Trio {
        let key: String
        let value: String
        let identifier: String
    }
    var trios = [Trio]()
        
    assert(rangeOfMotionResults.count == variableIdentifiers.count, "The size of rangeOfMotionResults and variableIdentifiers must be equal")
        
    for (index, result) in rangeOfMotionResults.enumerated() {
        identifier = variableIdentifiers[index]
            
        // add key-value pairs with their identifiers to array
        let orientation = String(result.orientation)
        trios.append(Trio(key: "orientation", value: orientation, identifier: identifier!))
            
        let start = String(result.start)
        trios.append(Trio(key: "start", value: start, identifier: identifier!))
            
        let finish = String(result.finish)
        trios.append(Trio(key: "finish", value: finish, identifier: identifier!))
            
        let minimum = String(result.minimum)
        trios.append(Trio(key: "minimum", value: minimum, identifier: identifier!))
            
        let maximum = String(result.maximum)
        trios.append(Trio(key: "maximum", value: maximum, identifier: identifier!))
            
        let range = String(result.range)
        trios.append(Trio(key: "range", value: range, identifier: identifier!))
    }
        
    for (_, result) in trios.enumerated() {
            
        let ident = result.identifier
        value = result.value
            
        let fieldName: String
        switch ident {
        case let id where id.contains("forward"):
            fieldName = result.key + "_forward"
        case let id where id.contains("backward"):
            fieldName = result.key + "_backward"
        case let id where id.contains("left.bending"):
            fieldName = result.key + "_left_bending"
        case let id where id.contains("right.bending"):
            fieldName = result.key + "_right_bending"
        case let id where id.contains("left.rotation"):
            fieldName = result.key + "_left_rotation"
        case let id where id.contains("right.rotation"):
            fieldName = result.key + "_left_rotation"
        default:
            fieldName = result.key + "_unknown"
        }
            
        let item = Item(record: record, fieldName: fieldName, repeatInstance: String(repeatInstance), repeatInstrument: repeatInstrument, value: value!, event: event)
            
        items.append(item)
    }
        
    do {
        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(items)
        stringData = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print(stringData!)

        // now do something with stringData

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the given scenario you need only these properties

```
func buildJsonArrayOfResults(_ rangeOfMotionResults: [ORKRangeOfMotionResult], withIdentifier variableIdentifiers: [String]) {
    let record = getIDNumber().stringValue
    let repeatInstance = getRepeatInstance().stringValue
    let repeatInstrument = "range_of_motion_result"
    let event = getEventName()
    var items: [Item] = []

    struct Item: Codable { ... }
```

And as the order of the identifiers match the order of the result array the recommended way to *enumerate* an array by index and element is `enumerated`

```
    for (index, result) in rangeOfMotionResults.enumerated() {
        let identifier = variableIdentifiers[index]
```

and it seems that `finish`, `minimum`, `maximum` and `range` are unused

```
       // obtain results for each set of movements as a string
        let orientation = String(result.orientation)
        let value = String(result.start)
```

a `switch` expression is *swiftier* than an `if - else` chain

```
        let fieldName : String

        switch identifier {
            case let id where id.contains("forward"): fieldName = "start_forward"
            case let id where id.contains("backward"): fieldName = "start_backward"
            case let id where id.contains("left.bending"): fieldName = "start_left_bending"
            case let id where id.contains("right.bending"): fieldName = "start_right_bending"
            case let id where id.contains("left.rotation"): fieldName = "start_left_rotation"
            case let id where id.contains("right.rotation"): fieldName = "start_left_rotation"
            default: fieldName = "unknown"
        }
        
        let item = Item(record: record, fieldName: fieldName, repeatInstance: repeatInstance, repeatInstrument: repeatInstrument, value: value, event: event)
        
        items.append(item)
    }

    do {
        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(items)
        let stringData = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
        print(stringData)

        // now do something with stringData
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

I recommend also to insert this line before the `for` loop

```
assert(rangeOfMotionResults.count == variableIdentifiers.count, "The size of rangeOfMotionResults and variableIdentifiers must be equal")
```

It checks if the sizes of both arrays are equal, the expression is ignored in a Release Build.

Comment: Many thanks indeed for this @vadian. It is far swiftier than my brain for sure. I don't want `finish`, `minimum`, `maximum` and `range` to be unused though. How can I iterate through these to add them to the json array?

Comment: Add properties in the `Item` struct and assign the values like the others.

Comment: So, my original `Item` struct needs to be amended for this?

Comment: Yes, all key/value pairs which are supposed to appear in the JSON must correspond to proprties and their values in the struct.

Comment: But this is the bit I'm stuck on. Your code is more beautiful than mine for sure, and offers more flexibility, but I still don't have the knowledge to rework the Codable struct and then amend your switch to iterate through the other properties of 'ORKRangeOfMotionResult' and assign the values for `start`, `finish`, `minimum`, `maximum` and `range`

Comment: The switch is only related to `identifier`. For example add `let minimum: String` to the struct and an appropriate CodingKey, then `let minimum = String(result.minimum)` and add the parameter also in the `init` method. As the JSON doesn't contain those keys this is the most detailed information I can give you. `start` is used and assigned to `value`